# Primeng p-dropdown icon chnage on mouse hover

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

My requirement is to change `primeng  dropdown` icon mouse over.

This is the actual **dropdown** icon

[image]

On the mouse over i need to change icon to this

[image]

I have added below style .

```
.pi-chevron-down:hover{
   color: mediumslateblue;
 }
```

This style will change the colour of the icon
How can i override the existing icon image.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/dropdown), there's an available property `dropdownIcon` that you can change. Something like:

```
<p-dropdown [dropdownIcon]="pi pi-check" [options]="cities"></p-dropdown>
```

Still keep in mind that you will probably have to use one of the icons they provide.

Edit 1. Sorry, missed the point of the hover requirement.

Edit 2. Here's a working solution taking into account the hover requirement :)
Essentially you just need to override the `.pi-chevron-down:before` selector using one of the [icons](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/icons) they provide.

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .p-dropdown:hover .pi-chevron-down:before {
    content: '\e987';
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Here's a working blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-vtagou